# C# Windows Forms - SendMessage EM_SETCUEBANNER on textbox not working

Tags: c#, textbox, placeholder, sendmessage

I'm making an application in C# with windows forms. I want to have a placeholder for my textboxes and I found the method of SendMessage from User32.dll. Here's my code (placed in LoginForm.cs which is one of the first forms if settings file doesn't exist):

private const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lParam);
```

Is placed inside the class. As my constructor I got:

```
public LoginForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SendMessage(hostname.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, "Hostname");
    SendMessage(port.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, "Port");
    SendMessage(username.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, "Username");
    SendMessage(password.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, "Password");
    SendMessage(database.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, "Database");
}
```

My `hostname`, `port`, `username`, `password`, `database` are all textboxes. But if I run my application, it doesn't apply the placeholders, it simply focuses on the last textbox.

What am I doing wrong? I get no errors.

Comment: Works fine for me, you have an autogenerated Application.EnableVisualStyles() in your main() ?

Comment: Oh, that's the problem, I didn't have. I started off with an empty Program.cs so I didn't have that line. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was dumb, I forgot to add `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` to my Program.cs.